# Spring SAML Application using two IDPs and different URLs

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I can’t seem to figure out how to use two different IDPS and 2 different applications URLs. I had this working on weblogic but not with a spring boot application using the spring saml security.

One important part is that we have two different URLs.

1. Proxy URL for external users. They must use this URL as they are not in the network.
   a. These users hit IDP-A
2. Internal URL for internal users.
   b. These users hit IDP-B

The metadata we sent to the each of the IDPs use the same entity ID but different endpoint URLs.

One thing we did was turn on discovery and where able to hit each IDP but it always redirects us to the internal URL. I noticed that AssertionConsumerServiceUrl is always set to the internal URL, which explains why it is returned to is the same. In our weblogic implementation we do not send AssertionConsumerServiceUrl.

Can we exclude AssertionConsumerServiceUrl?

Do you know if the configuration I am attempting to do is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can autowire the MetadataManager bean in your service and then call the addMetadataProvider to inititate a metadata.

You can get the entityId from the Metadata Obtained from IDP and can append to the url :
'http:///saml/login?idp=' by hitting this url it will redirect you to appropriate IDP login.

Comment: When I try that the sets the AssertionConsumerServiceUrl to URL A. I need it to not send the AssertionConsumerServiceUrl because if it does the IDP redirects me to that url even if it came from a different URL.
Do you know how to not send the AssertionConsumerServiceUrl?

Comment: default configuration found in the references of spring saml then only one SP metadata will be generated. because of which if you have two URLs abc.com & xyz.com then the first request to your server(from any of the two URLs) will set the AssertionConsumerServiceURL. e.g if the first request to server came from abc.com then the ACS URL will be set as abc.com. After that even if you send SAML requests through xyz.com your SP metadata will have abc.com in the URL. So the solution to this is you need to initialize as many local SP Metadata as many proxy URLs you have to access your application.